# Why is the stroke width at (0,y) coordinate is always thinner, and how to fix this?

Tags: html, svg

If you compare

```
<SVG>
  <PATH d="M 0 0  L 0 50" stroke="#FFFFFF" />
</SVG>
```

and

```
<SVG>
  <PATH d="M 1 0  L 1 50" stroke="#FFFFFF" />
</SVG>
```

you'll notice that the stroke is thinner in the first case, and is proper in the second case. Why is that? (It looks so in Firefox.) (You may want to change the stroke color if you have a white background by default.)

[image]

Comment: ```<svg>
  <path d="M 0 0 L 0 50" stroke="#FFFFFF" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you draw the SVG line path on the edge of the SVG container, then you will see only 1/2 of the line, because the other 1/2 is outside of the container and clipped.

Tip: you can see this more clearly, if you add a stroke-width

```
<PATH d="M 0 0  L 0 50" stroke="orange" stroke-width="6" />
```

and add an outline or border to your svg:

```
svg {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

If an SVG doesn't specify a viewBox, width or height, then the SVG will go from 0,0 to 300,150 by default.  Anything outside of this 0,0 to 300,150 box will be clipped.

The line starting at 0,0 is on the edge of the container and thus clipped in half.  The line starting at 1,0 is completely in the container.

If you want to see the entire line, even the part outside of the container, then add this css:

```
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg style="overflow:visible;background:lightgreen">
  <path fill="pink" d="M0 0h200v100h-200z" stroke="orange" stroke-width="6">
</svg>
```

[image]